# Vue 2, Axios custom instance, Vuex, and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

I am very new to using Typescript, but I am not having a great time with it and Vuex/Axios.

Setup: Vue CLI app, Vue 2, Vuex 3, Axios, Typescript

High level: I have a custom Axios instance where I am setting the baseURL, interceptors, timeout settings, etc.  I'm importing Axios and then using `axios.create()` to set my configs.

I want to use this instance of Axios from *any* component, or the Vuex store like so `this.$api.get()`

Right now, I have a file for my Axios instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const $api = axios.create(
  {
    baseURL: 'https://myapi.com',
    headers: {
      ...
    },
    timeout: 20000,
    timeoutErrorMessage: 'timeout',
    ...
  },
);

Vue.prototype.$api = $api;
```

In my Vuex store actions
store/index.ts

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  ...
  actions: {
    async fetchUser({ commit }): Promise<void> {
      const path = '/me';
      const user = await this.$api.get(path);

      commit('setUser', user);
    },
   }
});
```

Then my main.ts file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import store from './store';
import IndexPage from './pages/index.vue';

require('./plugins/api');

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(IndexPage),
}).$mount('#app');
```

But I'll get errors like this:
`Property '$api' does not exist on type 'Store<{ user: User; courses: Course[]; }>'.`

I've tried to use the Vue-axios npm package and access the API with  `Vue.$api.get()`

```
 Property '$api' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside any store, regardless if it's `vuex` or `pinia`, `this` is NOT the Vue instance.
Why? One possible reason would be that a store can be consumed by multiple Vue apps, at the same time.

In other words:

> I want to use this instance of Axios from any component, ***or the Vuex store*** like...

is ***not** possible*. Unless you import it in every store and declare it on the store instance. But there's no point in attaching it to the store. You can use it directly once imported.
In more detail, this is how it's typically done:

**some-file.ts**

```
export const $api = axios.create({...})
//
```

**in any store:**

```
import { $api } from '/path/to/some-file'
// 
// you can now use `$api` directly in any action, mutation, getter, etc...
```

Note: you should still register it on the Vue instance, so it's usable as `this.$api` in any component.